# Laravel Invention Image - How to DELETE image from Storage

Tags: laravel, image-processing

I created Laravel app where I wanted to upload images + resize and crop them, for that I used **Invention Image**

Here is my code how I'm storing images:

```
        /*just image cropping + resizing*/
        $light_image = Image::make($request->file('startup_screenshot'));

        $light_image->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $light_image->crop(300, 275, 0, 0);
        $light_image->encode('jpg');
        /*just image cropping + resizing*/

        /*image storing*/
        $hashed_light_image = md5($light_image->__toString());
        $light_image_name =  $hashed_light_image . time() . '.jpg';
        Storage::put('public/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/' . $light_image_name, $light_image->__toString());
        $path_to_light_image = '/storage/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/' . $light_image_name;
       /*image storing*/
```

I tried to use this code to delete images but it doesn't work:

```
...
$startup_to_update = Startup::find($request->id);

Storage::delete($startup_to_update->screenshot);
Storage::delete($startup_to_update->screenshot_light); // pay attention
...
```

**How Can I delete those images  ?**

Thank you all very much for any ideas! 
I realy appreciate this ))

Comment: What values do `$startup_to_update->screenshot` and `$startup_to_update->screenshot_light` contain? Are they complete paths? I.e. is `Storage::delete()` calling `Storage::delete("/storage/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/example.jpg")` or just `Storage::delete("example.jpg")`? Also, when you say *"[...] it doesn't work"* are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: I'm getting smth like that "/storage/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/image_name.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

From what you write we can only get conjetures but well, are you sure that you are storing the correct path?, remember that Storage will be storage/app (you can check it in config->filesystem) so it would be stored in

```
storage/app/public/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/ . $light_image_name
```

But for what i can see/think you are looking inside of

```
/storage/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/' . $light_image_name
```

in any case if you think that what is inside $startup_to_update is the real path then you can check if it exist with

```
Storage::has($direction)
```

if it return true, then the file exist and you may have a problem with permissions.

ProTip, for these cases i use to make my own disk inside config->filesystems.php

```
'light_previews' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('/app/public/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'storage/app/public/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

And then i use it like these

```
Storage::disk('light_previews')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($file));//store
Storage::disk('light_previews')->delete($fileName);//delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use intervention to delete images from storage. Intervention only acts as a image helper, not a file system helper.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete(file_path_of_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, path wasn't correct, 
I used this type of path to store my images: ***"/storage/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/image_name.jpg"*** , you can see code example below:

```
Storage::put('public/images/startups-screenshots/light_previews/' . $light_image_name, $light_image->__toString());
```

As you can see I used **"public/images/...."** on the begining, but when I tried to delete this I couldn't because I should point path of that type **"public/images/...."** , not that one which I used: **"/storage/images/...."**

**so I just changed path from "public/images/...." to "public/images/...."**

and it works now

Thanks all for good ideas!